# Cordova-iOS 3.7.0 issues with icon validation (pre cli-4.1 release)

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I have had a issue with the new Cordova-ios 3.7.0

From cordova.apache.org they say the new 3.7.0 will be the default version of cordova-ios for cordova-cli 4.1

Until 4.1 is released I added the new version explicitly (as per the news update suggested) - but it have failing validation for "missing required icon" for the 120x120 version, when only enabling iPhone devices and targeting ios 7 or 8.

One standard icon for all devices is add in the config file (and have passed before).

Does I have to wait for cli-4.1 for this to work properly or is it a bug or am I doing something wrong (perhaps missing some new documentation for cordova-ios 3.7.0 that I just can't find)

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it works fine just adding it yourself in the config.xml

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="icon120.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
```

Adding the second line did the trick, but I never had to do this before.